# Convert IST to PST in java

Tags: java, datetime

Hi 
      I have a date/Time field i want to get Convert current IST to CURRENT PST in java... need help....

ex: now in IST its :`13/may/2011 3.32.58pm` want the same in PST i.e. `13/may/2011 3.02.58 AM`

thank you........

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're interested in the *current* time, you don't need to know about IST at all... just the current instance, and the conversion to PST. You can do this with something like:

```
Date now = new Date();
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"); // For example...
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("..."); // Put your pattern here
format.setTimeZone(zone);
String text = format.format(now);
```

Personally I'd recommend you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) for all date/time work instead, as it's a much nicer API - but in this case it's really pretty simple even with the built-in API.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5990353/642706) is correct but now outdated with the arrival of the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) code in Java 8 and later.

## java.time

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

Get current moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Adjust into a time zone.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

To generate a String in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, call the `toString`. For alternate formatting, use the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class already covered in many other Questions and Answers.

```
String output = zdt.format( myDateTimeFormatter );
```

See the same moment in [India time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_India), specifically [`Asia/Kolkata`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Kolkata).

```
ZoneId zKolkata = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( zKolkata );
```

I am not sure if by `IST` you meant India Standard Time or Irish Standard Time. Let's cover `Europe/Dublin` as well. That zone happens to currently use an offset of zero, `+00:00`. So its [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) in the same as UTC.

```
ZoneId zDublin = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Dublin" );
ZonedDateTime zdtDublin = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( zDublin );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/B006Mq).

> instant.toString(): 2017-02-13T07:28:57.738Z
>
> zdt.toString(): 2017-02-12T23:28:57.738-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
>
> zdtKolkata.toString(): 2017-02-13T12:58:57.738+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
>
> zdtDublin.toString(): 2017-02-13T07:28:57.738Z[Europe/Dublin]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).